# ¿Como consumir un Webservice que devuelve un Json a traves de una URL? en PHP

Tags: php, json, webservice

Me gustaria saber si existe algun metodo para consumir Webservices de tipo Restful el cual me devolveria un JSON con los datos que necesito y dependiendo si hay valores en el objeto colocarlos en el input el codigo que utilizo es el siguiente, quisiera saber si hay un mejor metodo.

```
 <?php

   $data = file_get_contents("https://uinames.com/api/?ext");
   $valores = json_decode($data, true);

 ?>
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: usa curl para hacer peticiones desde el servidor. te recomiendo que uses guzzle es mas fácil de usar. Pero la base son las peticiones curl

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un `file_get_content`, y luego un `json_decode` para que te devuelva un `json`.

- Ejemplo, consultas la api de mercado libre de un usuario en especifico.

```
      <?php
        echo file_get_contents('https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/226384143/');
```

- Luego el decode, para que te devuelva en formato json.

```
    <?php
    $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/226384143/'),true );
```

- Luego imprimes el nickname de la data que te retorno.

```
echo $data['nickname'];
```

Comment: Gracias, lo he probado y me ha sido de buena utilidad